# How can I paginate documents and handle a pageToken in Firestore?

Tags: java, api, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a java REST API allowing the UI to list documents from Firestore (potentially ordering it on multiple fields).
I'm following the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) but I'm struggling about how to handle/generate a next page token (since the UI will potentially need to iterate over and over) from the response. Is there any way to implement this behavior with the GRPC client? Should I switch to the REST client (which seems to expose a nextPageToken field)?

Comment: How are you interacting into the pages, if you are performing asynchronous requests it could be possible to store the token for the session on the client. And if you are navigating between pages you should use it by passing it. 
Are you getting 403/401 errors in your requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround I found to mime a pagination-like behavior:

```
public <T extends InternalModel> Page<T> paginate(@NonNull Integer maxResults, @Nullable String pageToken) {
    try (Firestore db = getFirestoreService()) {
        CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection(getCollection(type));
        Query query = collectionReference
                .limit(maxResults);

        // The page token is the id of the last document
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(pageToken)) {
            DocumentSnapshot lastDocument = collectionReference.document(pageToken).get().get();
            query = query.startAfter(lastDocument);
        }

        List<InternalModel> items = (List<InternalModel>) query.get().get().toObjects(type);
        String nextPageToken = "";
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(items) && maxResults.equals(items.size())) {
            nextPageToken = items.get(items.size() - 1).getId();
        }

        return Page.create(items, nextPageToken);
    }
}
```

I'm opened to any better solution since this might not be the most optimal way.